# Magento - Displaying additional information on Customer Control Panel

Tags: magento, module

A client asked me to integrate Magento's Customer Control Panel with some additional information, to be retrieved from an external Web Service. At the moment, I have some small, standalone code that can query such Web Service and retrieve the necessary data. What I need to do is integrating such code within Magento and display the data on the Control Panel.

The quickest (and dirtiest) way, from what I've seen, would be to "brutally" hard code the call into the dashboard.phtml file. The data is not too complex, therefore this could be an option to get a proof of concept working quickly.

However, I'd like to reuse this feature on several websites, and it also requires some configuration which would be painful to maintain as hardcoded variables. Besides, the above is a hack, more than a solution.

It's clear, then, that I need to develop a proper module.

**The question**
I know how to create a basic module, with its configuration page and a simple controller. What I'd like to understand is, once I implement a method to fetch the external data, is the following:

- Where should I put the method, and how should I call it?
- How should I pass the data to the dashboard.phtml for rendering?

I could probably find "a way" to do the above, but I'm quite sure I'd end up with a hack more than a solution, therefore any help in learning the Magento ways is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can :

- create a new module
- add a observer for your dashboard before_html or after_html event (one is called before template is rendered and other when template is already rendered)
- add your method to your observer that outputs the content you receive from webservice to the block output (before or after the content) automatically

you can :

- create a new module
- create a block that has your methods for webservice
- add a layout handler to layout file with your block reference
- edit the template and call your block from there and get the data for this
- optionally you can make your own template as well and call the block output in your template

you can:

- create a new module
- add a template and implement all things in template
- use layout files to replace the template used originally

Comment: Thanks Anton. I'm not sure which one would be the best approach. The first looks much simpler, but I need to add stuff in the dashboard HTML and before or after HTML would both not be the "right moments" to do it. However, I'm not an expert and I'll have to see it for myself. Would you be so kind to tell me where I can find more details on implementing what you suggested?

Comment: if the before and after are not right places then you have to choose the second one or come out with another approach, there are plenty of other ways to solve this as well

Comment: I think I made some confusion, my statement was not clear. I don't really know very well Magento, therefore I based my assumption about the before/after HTML on their name. Since I have to alter the way the HTML is rendered, to make space for my new data, before and after sounded like "too early and too late". About the other ways to do it, I'm sure there are plenty of them, the issue is my knowledge of Magento is superficial and I'd like to listen to someone with more experience rather than spending days on Google and basing my solution on guesswork. :)

Comment: good luck on learning Magento then :) no-one will give you a complete solution without code samples of your own I'm afraid. If you don't have time to learn new things then you most certainly can buy other's time.

Comment: I have provided you with 2 ideas already, check my post i added 1 more. So go ahead and implement one of those and you can edit your post here if you have issues in doing it.

Comment: Funnily enough, the third suggestion is what I was doing already, just to get something going. After all, it seemed the most logical approach from a generic MVC perspective. I guess I'll use good old DIY method, so I can finally get over it. By the way, I 100% agree that it would be a good idea to get an expert to do this stuff, as I'm really not interested in mastering Magento. Whether the customer is willing to pay their rates or not, that's another story... Thanks for your help.